# Replicate password obfuscation to programatically login to a website with curl

Tags: curl, webforms

I want to submit/simulate a login webform with curl. I'm using....

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/login
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"cpuid":"my_login","password":"my_password"}'
```

The form works but I get an incorrect password response.

When I inspect the actual GUI login screen, the "password" key/value looks obfuscated in the request.

How can I replicate whatever the web page is doing?

Here is an example (I have changed the values)...

GUI password submission = "TPqWKSFz^D63R8"

What was actually submitted....
[image]

I appreciate I might be at a dead end here as there may be all sorts of options used for encrypting passwords in transit. It's not B64 encoded I know that. Maybe I can look deeper into the page js to see if a function is used there? Or is it likely to be server side?

Edit: Looks like there is a sha1 script running... is this a standard thing?

Edit2: As a hacky way round this I can use the actual website to hash the password beforehand and grab it out of the inspector to store that for use.

Comment: I wonder if I need to be using Python/Selenium headless to store the session cookie first

Comment: The form submit in the browser should be attached to a JS event. Somewhere in the JS it is hashing the password. It's probably very simple and easy to replicate. You could store it, but not unless it changes every time. It may use a random salt.

Comment: It is just sha1? a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3 = "test".

Comment: Yeah seems to be. I'll try it :)

Comment: I tried sha1 and MD5 scripts in Google sheets and am not getting the same string.

Comment: Here is the function https://pastebin.com/FxzZC618

Seems more complex than I expected. I wasn't able to convert it to a Google Sheets script.

Comment: OK got my Google script working from https://pthree.org/2016/02/26/digest-algorithms-in-google-spreadsheets/

Doesn't seem to be a random element. Now I have to work out how to store the cookie and redirect to index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, yes it ended up being SHA1. I grabbed a SHA1 script from [here](https://pthree.org/2016/02/26/digest-algorithms-in-google-spreadsheets/) and added it to Google Sheets scripts to generate the hash. I chose Sheets only because I already had a doc I was sharing with non technical folks which builds up the curl query to run with some defined variables.

Here's the relevant code in case the link goes down...

```
function SHA1(s) {
  var hexstr = '';
  var digest = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_1, s)
  for (i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
    var val = (digest[i]+256) % 256;
    hexstr += ('0'+val.toString(16)).slice(-2);
  }
  return hexstr
```

Now I can use a the hash in curl to retrieve a session cookie from the /login endpoint, and query the local website programmatically to scrape the info off the HTML page that is needed.

Slightly off topic but to do that I'm doing the following...

```
curl --cookie-jar cookie -X POST http://<LOCAL IP>/login -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"cpuid":"<CPU ID>","password":"<PASSWORD>"}'
```

and then...

```
curl -L http://<LOCAL IP> --cookie cookie | grep <search term>
```

The grep is just to filter out the HTML source noise.